# ARCGis Xamarin - MapView from previous page displays after navigating to new page

Tags: xamarin, arcgis

I have a 'main' map page from which the user can either add data to the map or click on existing data to see the details.  This is done with PushModalAsync() where I navigate to a new page.  My problem is in both of those new pages I have a new map with a new MapView that is 'underneath' the MapView from the 'main' page.  Both the MapView and Map itself are new objects on the secondary pages.

After navigating to my new pages, the previous MapView shows in the area of the screen where it existed (on 'main' page) where my new MapView also exists.  In other words, on my new map pages my map is laid out differently and partially sits higher in the layout than the 'main' map does.  The part that sits higher is the only part of the new map that is visible and I can interact with.  The part that sits on the same area is the 'main' map view and I cannot interact with it and it blocks my new map.

I tried this with PushAsync as well (not modal) and nothing changed.  How is one supposed to have multiple maps in an app across multiple pages?  Is this even possible with ArcGIS?  This app used to be with Google Maps/Apple and the exact same layout worked just fine.

[image: My main map page in yellow is the area where my future map, in a new page, is supposed to display]

[image: My new page, with new MapView and new map, covered by previous map]

Edit: Code here (with irrelevant parts removed)  This page is navigated to from another page with a map on it wherein this map is covered if it is laid out in the same area of the first map.  From this page I navigate to a 3rd page where both maps show up.  Removal works successfully, however when I try to add I get an error saying I cannot add a null child to a view group:

```
public partial class EventDetails : ContentPage
{
    public Xamarin.Forms.Grid MapGrid = new Xamarin.Forms.Grid()
    {
    RowDefinitions =
    {
        new RowDefinition { Height = 220 },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
    },
    ColumnDefinitions =
    {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = 500 }
    },
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };
    public Map DetailMap;
    public MapView MyDetailMapView = new MapView();

    public EventDetails(MapLog eventDetails, string strMapType)
    {    
        DetailMap = new Map(BasemapType.ImageryWithLabels, eventDetails.Latitude, eventDetails.Longitude, iMapDetail);
        MyDetailMapView.Map = DetailMap;
        MyDetailMapView.ViewpointChanged += MyMapView_ViewpointChanged;
        var scrollView = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = mainStack
        };
        MapGrid.Children.Add(MyDetailMapView, 0, 0);
        MapGrid.Children.Add(scrollView, 0, 1);
        Content = MapGrid;
    }

#if __ANDROID__ 
protected override void OnAppearing()
{

    if (!MapGrid.Children.Contains(MyDetailMapView))
    {
        try
        {
            MapGrid.Children.Add(MyDetailMapView);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Err", ex.Message, "Ok");           
        }

    }
    base.OnAppearing();

 }

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    if (MapGrid.Children.Contains(MyDetailMapView))
        MapGrid.Children.Remove(MyDetailMapView);
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
#endif
}
```

EDIT*: I updated my Xamarin Forms version and ARCGIS Runtime and now the solution to remove/add the map does work without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had other similar problems with having two maps for android in Xamarin Forms ArcGIS and the solution was removing the MapView from the visual tree when you navigate to the new page.
You need to remove the MapView before you Navigate to the second page by:

```
[your parent layout].Children.Remove(MyMapView);
await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
```

And in your first page you need to make sure to add the MapView back to the Visual Tree when you come back to the page:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (!GridMap.Children.Contains(MyMapView))
            GridMap.Children.Add(MyMapView);
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

That solved all my problems with two maps. Thanks to this post in ESRI forum
[Navigation between 2 MapViews in Xamarin Android](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/195773-navigation-between-2-mapviews-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this definitely helps.

Can you clarify something though on your fix.  My MapView is in a Xamarin Forms Grid, and that Grid is my ContentPage's Content.  

I got it to disappear by removing it from the Grid, but when I try to re-add it OnAppearing I get an error "Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup". 

When you add it back, are you adding it back to a Xamarin Forms Grid?  In my debug I can see the Grid is not null nor is the MapView.  Any idea?

Comment: Yes I am adding the MapView to a Grid. Can you post your code in your question?

Comment: code below, sorry not sure why it won't show the spacing correctly

`protected override void OnAppearing()
{ 

       if (!MapGrid.Children.Contains(MyDetailMapView)) { 
             MapGrid.Children.Add(MyDetailMapView); 
        } 
base.OnAppearing(); 
} 

protected override void OnDisappearing() 
{ 
       if (MapGrid.Children.Contains(MyDetailMapView)) 
              MapGrid.Children.Remove(MyDetailMapView); 

base.OnDisappearing(); 
}`

Comment: I don't remove the MapView in `OnDisappearing()` because while I was testing I noticed that Xamarin first fires `OnAppearing()` for the new screen and then calls `OnDisappearing` for the old screen @user2820951

Comment: I tried that too and it throws the exact same error.

So frustrating.

Comment: Maybe post all parts of your code, like the View, ViewModel in your question

Comment: I updated original post with code.  Not using a ViewModel (although I tried using one wherein my MapView was a member of the ViewModel and it did not change anything).  Somebody in the Xamarin Forums said that removing the MapView from the grid destroys the object so it's expected that it be NULL (even though it's not in my debugger).